# Install Android 4.1 on unknown custom Chinese tablet with X210 processor

Tags: custom-roms, 4.1-jelly-bean, tablet

I want to install Android 4.1 on a custom tablet running custom hardware and a custom Android 4.0.4 because I need TLS 1.2 to work on it.

I understand there is quite a big chance of bricking the tablet but I'm willing to risk it.

Here is some info for the device

- Device Model: Unknown
- Android: 4.0.4
- Processor: X210 (armeabi-v7a)
- Processor frequency: Unknown
- Cores: 1
- Audio chipset: X210
- GPU: Imagination Technologies Power VR SGX 540
- Display resolution: 753x480 @68 Hz (6.2")
- RAM: 381 MB
- Internal Storage: 540 MB

I'm just not sure how to go about it or what ROM should I use.

Do I try to find an original Google ROM or one of those custom CyanogenMod ones? I want to try something with the maximum chance of success, so any tips and guides are highly appreciated.

Comment: Google only provides ROM for Google devices. Though, without knowing the device model/maker, there's almost no chance. The real issue is that [there is no generic ROM in Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/82359/44325)

Comment: Basically the same as [How to install a custom ROM on a generic Chinese Android tablet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/185851/44325) which even for the community is a difficult task to answer satisfyingly.